# Expectation, supremum and convergence.

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, expectation, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

I have been reading the Karoui's paper about [Reflected Backward Stochastic Diffrential Equation](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aop/1024404416).

> Let $b:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^d$ and $\sigma:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be continuous mappings, which are Lipschitz with respect to their second variable, uniformly
>   with respect to $t\in[0,T]$. For each $(t,x)\in[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d$, let $\left\{X_{s}^{t,x}; t\leq s\leq T\right\}$ be the unique $\mathbb{R}^d$-valued solution of the SDE:
>   $$X_{s}^{t,x}=x+\int_{t}^{s}b(r,X_{r}^{t,x})dr+\int_{t}^{s}\sigma(r,X_{r}^{t,x})dBr.$$
>   On page number 729, they say that
>   $$\begin{align*} \mathbb{E}(\left|g(X_T^{t,x}
> )-g(X_T^{t_n,x_n})\right|^{2})&\rightarrow 0 \\
> \mathbb{E}(\displaystyle\sup_{0\leq s\leq T}\left|h(s,X_s^{t,x}
> )-h(s,X_s^{t_n,x_n})\right|^{2})&\rightarrow 0, \end{align*}$$
>
> where $g\in C(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and has most polynomial growth at infinity and $h:[0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is jointly continuous in $t$ and $x$ and satisfies
>
> $$h(t,x)\leq K(1+\left|x\right|^p), \hspace{1cm} t\in[0,T], x\in\mathbb{R}^d$$
>
> and
>
> $$h(T,x)\leq g(x), \hspace{0.5cm} x\in\mathbb{R}.$$

So, I think that the first convergence is thanks to dominated convergence theorem (DCT), since for $\omega\in \Omega$ we have $g(X_T^{t_n,x_n}(\omega))\rightarrow g(X_{T}^{t,x}(\omega))$ by the continuity of $g$, $X_T^{t,x}$ (respect to the initial conditions $t$ and $x$) and

$\mathbb{E}(|g(X_T^{t,x})|^2)\leq\mathbb{E}(C(1+|X_T^{t,x}|^2))\leq C(1+|x|^2)<\infty$.

Am I right or wrong? if I am right, can I use the same idea for the second convergence? or, is the supremum a problem in order to do it ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @saz, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: You can't apply the dominated convergence theorem that way; note that the dominated convergence theorem requires an (integrable) bound which does not depend on $n$; this means essentially that you have to show $$\mathbb{E} \left( \sup_{x \in K} g(X_T^{t,x})^2 \right) < \infty$$ for compact sets $K$.